# Pre Populate a field in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can someone provide high level pointers for this ?

Pre populate a text field (T1) in VF page based on another field's(T2) data.

Both T1 and T2 are fields in the same object.

The user can overwrite the prepopulated text on T1 if he/she desires.

EDIT :

The text which I will be prepopulating is over 7000 characters

a) I cannot use custom Label becuase of 1000 char limit.

b) I don't want to use Javascript function because the page size will become higher because of the text size.

c) I could not use Custom Settings because of 255 char limit on text fields in Custom settings.

I am thinking of creating 1-record custom object just for this purpose.
Am I on the correct path ?

Comment: one option is to use javascript and prefill a text box when another field value changes.

Comment: Please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<apex: inputField value = "T2"  onChange = "passStringToController(new value); return false;"" /> 

<apex:actionFunction name="passStringToController" action="{!myMethod}" rerender="T1">
    <apex:param name="p1" value="" assignTo="{!myString}" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex: inputField value = "T1"  id = "T1" />
```

in apex class You have to set the value T1 in get methods based on mystring variable

Comment: Tx for the suggestion. Please check my edit and let know